# TypeError: string indices must be integers. Что не так?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlite3

TypeError: string indices must be integers

Код:

```
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Login = '%s'" % (Id1))
                row=cur.fetchone()
                print(row[0]["Id"])
```

Таблица:
[image: Users]

Comment: В ошибке же простым понятным языком написано, что не так.

Comment: @Эникейщик Только что попробовал(row["Id"]), вот ответ: TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: Потому что вы не прочитали текст ошибки.

Comment: я прочитал, но не знаю как исправить.

Comment: Если написано, что индекс должен быть целым числом, то чем должен быть индекс?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так `row=cur.fetchone()` вам выдаёт одну запись. Что-то одно видимо надо тут использовать - либо `row[0]` либо `row["Id"]` (но что так сработает я не уверен), потому что `row[0]` вам уже выдаёт строку со значением поля БД и вы пытаетесь от этой строки взять индекс `["Id"]`, чего `Python` уже не может понять, что вы собственно от него хотите.

Comment: Только что попробовал, вот ответ:
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: @Андрей Ну, значит оно вообще индексацию в виде строк не понимает, только в виде целых чисел. `row[0]` работает?

Comment: Работает, наугад попробовал-заработало. Спасибо!